# Attempting to make a multi-column graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, python, charts, matplotlib

I am trying to make a column graph where the y-axis is the mean grain size, the x-axis is the distance along the transect, and each series is a date and/or number value (doesn't really matter).

Here is an [image of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0l1W.png)
and here it is in CSV format:

```
Date,,Grain Size (mm),Distance along Transact
8/7/2013,2,0.7912,9
4/5/2014,3,0.513,9
6/5/2015,4,0.4644,9
6/26/2013,1,1.0852,12
6/5/2015,4,1.8515,12
8/7/2013,2,1.812,15
4/5/2014,3,6.371,15
6/5/2015,4,1.602,15
6/26/2013,1,1.0251,17
6/5/2015,4,5.6884,17
6/26/2013,1,0.4166,25
6/5/2015,4,24.8669,25
6/26/2013,1,0.5223,32.5
6/5/2015,4,37.387,32.5
6/26/2013,1,0.5159,39.5
6/5/2015,4,0.6727,39.5
```

I have been trying a few different methods in Excel 2010 but I cannot figure it out. My hope is that, let's say at the first location, 9, there will be three columns and then at 12 there will be two columns. If it matters at all, let's say the total distance is 50. The result of this data should have 7 sets of columns along the transect/x-axis.

I have tried to do this using python but my coding knowledge is close to nil. Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
grainsize = [0.7912, 0.513, 0.4644, 1.0852, 1.8515, 1.812, 6.371, 1.602, 1.0251, 5.6884, 0.4166, 24.8669, 0.5223, 37.387, 0.5159, 0.6727]
series = [2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4]
distance = [9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 25, 25, 32.5, 32.5, 39.5, 39.5]
```

If someone happen to know of a code to use, it would be very helpful. A recommendation for how to do this in Excel would be awesome too.

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Coding questions belong on stackoverflow.com, so you might consider splitting this into two questions. Also, you say you've tried a few different methods in Excel, you should include details on what you've tried, both so people trying to answer the question don't waste time trying something that won't work, and someone may be able to tweak something you've tried to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one idea: Create a new table that tabulates the data differently and make a chart off that. It's not a perfect solution but it works and it's easy to expand as your data grows.

First, here's what the result looks like:

[image: Final Product]

You can see your original data in columns `A:D`. I actually modified it because there were two very large values and they made it hard to see the three columns. In `F1:I8` is the table I made and the chart is in the bottom right. Here's how you can repeat the process:

1. Figure out how many times the most frequent value appears in the `Distance along Transact` column (referred to as just `Distance` from now on). An easy way to do this is with the formula `=COUNTIF(D:D,MODE(D:D))`.
2. Create that many columns in your new table and just use numbers as their header. (1, 2, 3, ...)
3. In `F2`, use the formula: `=SMALL(D:D,1)` to get the lowest `Distance` value.
4. In `F3`, use the ***array*** formula `{=SMALL(IF(D:D>F2,D:D),1)}` (enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and drag down the formula as needed.
5. In `G2`, use the ***array*** formula `{=INDEX($C:$C,SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$17=$F2,ROW($D$2:$D$17),9E+99),G$1))}` and drag it down and over to fill the table. Ignore the `#REF!` errors as they won't show up on the chart.
6. Create a chart based on the new table's range.

The only editing I did for the screenshot above was to reduce the gaps between columns so you could see it better.

The downside to this method is that it leaves blank spaces between the X-Axis values if it has less than the maximum number of `Grain Size` data points. If you want to add data labels, then the errors will show up as zero so format the data labels with the custom format `#,##0;-#,##0;;` to hide the zeros.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I was able to manipulate a few things based on your recommendation. Thanks again for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option to consider, using Excel's built-in efficiencies with Tables and Pivot Tables.

1. Convert your data into columns  `Data > Text-to-Columns`
2. Create an Excel Table from your data (with a cell in your data selected) `Insert > Table`
3. Create a Pivot Table from your Table (with a cell in your Table selected) `Insert > Pivot Table`, with the following settings:

   - Column Labels:  **Column 1**
   - Row Labels:  **Distance Along Transact**
   - Values:  **Average of Grain Size**
4. Create a Pivot Chart from your Pivot Table (with a cell in your Pivot Table selected) `Insert > Charts > 2-D Column Chart`

[image: Excel Tables and Charts]

Now, without any formulas you have a linked series of objects that will refresh with changes amongst them (e.g. adding rows to your data table, filtering your pivot chart or pivot table).

To get maximum value from this solution, you can set your table up to automatically refresh from different data sources (e.g. SQL Server), ensuring your tables/charts are always up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if a column chart is really the best way to show grain size vs position, I'd try a scatter chart.

First, I made a pivot table to arrange the data in a better layout, with dates in the columns area, distance in the rows area, and average grain size as the values. This is in E1:I9 in the screenshot.

You can't make a scatter chart as a pivot chart. You can make one if you add the data series by series, long story, but instead, I copied the pivot table and pasted as values in another range (E12:I19 in my screen shot), and I made sure the top left cell (E12) was blank.

Then I made my scatter plot, and in the select data dialog, I clicked on hidden and empty cells, and selected the option to draw a line connecting points on either side of a missing cell.

[image: grain size vs position]

Something looks funny in the most recent measurements!